# How to get an array object response in @Query annotation in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-repositories

I am working with AngularJS and Spring Boot technologies for my project tasks, and I am new to Spring. I use `@Query` annotation with `nativeQuery=true` in my Spring repository and I want to get an array of objects response.

Example of Response:

```
[{id: 1, name: "John Michael", age: 19, company_position: "Programmer"}]
```

This is an example of my Query:

```
SELECT q.id, q.name, q.age, w.company_position FROM employee q, company w WHERE q.id=w.emp_id;
```

How to get an array object response in `@Query` annotation in Spring?

Comment: There is no need for a native query. If your query returns a `List<Employee>` this will automatically be serialized as an array when you later return it from a `Conteoller` using the `@ResponseBody` annotation. The getters on `Employee` is used to find the properties used in the JSON

Comment: But my query will return columns from 2 tables. and it supposted to return column from Employee class and Company class. The name and age is from Employee class and the id and company position is from Company Class.

Comment: Personally I never use my Entity classes as DTO. So I would create a new DTO class for the JSON, and copy the data into it. You can read why here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820194/should-i-consider-using-dto-for-spring-rest-controller-layers-instead-of-entitie/43823840#43823840

Comment: If you create a DTO you can have JPA create it, by selecting values directly into the constructor using the `SELECT new com.eample.EmployerAndCompany(q.id, q.name, q.age, w.company_position) FROM employee q, company w WHERE q.id=w.emp_id;`. Still no need for a native query, it is supported directly by JPQL. This is called a projection query.

Comment: Can you construct a a code example? Im a little bit confused. Sorry.

Comment: I can do an example. However from the query above I think your data model is wrong. The company tables stores the position name ? sounds like that should be on the employee table, unless an employee can have multiple positions, in which case it should be in a separate mapping table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two examples. In the entity is loaded, and the data copied to the DTO. In the second example a prection query is used to minimize data load and copying. I have change the original query to select the company name, since it does not make since to store employ position in the company table. Lombok annotations are used to create getter/setter and constructors.

Employee class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private int age;

    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;
}
```

Company class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Company {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Employee> employees;
}
```

A simple POJO class (DTO) for generating the JSON the way we want.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeAndCompanyDTO {

    String name;
    int age;
    String companyName;
}
```

Spring Data repository

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

Example Rest Controller

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @ResponseBody
    public List<EmployeeAndCompanyDTO> employeeAndCompanyView() {
        List<Employee> employee = employeeRepository.findAll();
        return employee.stream()
                .map(e-> new EmployeeAndCompanyDTO(e.getId(), e.getName(), e.getAge(), e.getCompany().getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

If you wanted to avoid loading all the data, but only load the columns you need you could use a custom projection query in the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    @Query("select new com.example.EmployeeAndCompanyDTO(e.id, e.name, e.age, e.company.name) from Employee e")
    List<EmployeeAndCompanyDTO> employeeAndCompanyView();

}
```

Writing the projection query is a bit more tricky (depending on your IDE support), but you load less data, and there is no need to convert from entity to DTO in you controller/service classes.